# Trouble in installing octave 4.0.1

Tags: 16.04, octave, gnu

I have tried installing octave 4.0.1 many times but it always shows errors whenever I run "make" command after "./configure" , but directory has 2 makefiles (Makefile.am, Makefile.in)

[Image showing output from ./configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uishA.png)

```
ubuntu@ubuntu$ make

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Comment: Neither `Makefile.am` nor `Makefile.in` is a `Makefile`. You will need to correct the errors reported by the `./configure` script until it completes successfully - or make do with octave 4.0.0 which is available direct from the `universe` repository

Comment: @steeldriver  Our instructor tells us that it is broken and we should install either 4.0.1 or higher version also there is an error    `configure: error: to build Octave, you must have the PCRE library and header files installed`

Comment: Then try https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/ --> 4.2.1

Comment: If you are given no option than to build 4.0.1 from source, then you will need to resolve each of the errors from the configure stage - simply re-running it and hoping isn't going to help. For the PCRE error, you likely need to install the `libpcre3-dev` package - but there may well be a series of other dependencies. I'm not generally a fan of `build-dep` but since 4.0.1 is only a minor point release different from 4.0.0 you may find that `sudo apt-get build-dep octave` is sufficient to resolve them.

Comment: . . . if 4.2.1 is an acceptable substitute, then it is [available from the Octave stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~octave/+archive/ubuntu/stable?field.series_filter=xenial)